# .NET listbox to SQLite DB

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, listbox

I'm fairly unfamiliar with SQLite and am trying to take items from a listbox and throw them into a simple database. Create the database (if it doesn't exist), then fill it, that's all. I've been playing around with it for a few days now and can't seem to get the correct syntax down.

```
 public SQLiteConnection createDatabase()
    {
         try
        {
            var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source= DB.db;Version=3");
            conn.Open();
            return conn;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new IOException("Unable to connect to database.", e);
        }

    }

    public void ImportDB()
    {
        SQLiteConnection conn= createDatabase();

        SQLiteCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOG(ENTRY varchar(300))";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        for(int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            string str = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO LOG(ENTRY) Values(@str);";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@ENTRY", str));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: do you see any errors?

Comment: @harandk nah, varchar should be fine i believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `SQLiteParameter("@str", str)`. 
You need to bind to your configured parameter, which is `@str` not `@ENTRY`

Comment: @Kayla Johnston please accept the answer when it was appropriate